# Set local image as a splash screen

Tags: 18.04, themes, plymouth

How to set a local image as splash screen for Ubuntu 18.04?

Every resource I find is about how to set one of the Plymouth themes as a splash screen but none of them explains how to set a local image as a splash screen.

Answer (score 2):

- Download some image with appropriate resolution (I've downloaded [this one](http://wallpapers-images.ru/1366x768/forest/wallpapers/forest-wallpapers-1366x768-0000.jpg))
- Copy it into appropriate place: `sudo cp ~/Pictures/wallpapers/forest-wallpapers-1366x768-0000.jpg /boot/grub/nsplash.jpg`
- Run `sudo update-grub`
- Reboot

The next could be helpful if previous method did not work:

- Edit `/etc/default/grub` file and put there the next:

  ```
  GRUB_BACKGROUND="/boot/grub/nsplash.jpg"
  ```

  You could specify a different path to image.
- Run `sudo update-grub`
- Reboot

> Choosing a GRUB 2 Background Image
>  GRUB 2 can use PNG, JPG/JPEG
>   and TGA images for the background. The image must meet the following
>   specifications:
>
> JPG/JPEG images must be 8-bit (256 color). Else you will get errors
>   saying "Too many Huffman tables". Since most of the time you will not
>   want to limit yourself to 256 colors (which is totally yesteryear) you
>   will probably find PNG much preferable.
>  Images should be
>   non-indexed, RGB.
>  The GIMP image editor is one application which
>   can edit images to conform to the GRUB 2 standards. Use the Image >
>   Mode menu options to set the properties to RGB and ensure the mode is
>   not set to Indexed.
>
> Sample GRUB 2 splash images are contained in the grub2-splashimages
>   package in the Universe repository. The package can be installed in
>   several ways:
>
> Synaptic (if installed). Select and install `grub2-splashimages`.
>
> Ubuntu Software Center. Search for `grub2-splashimages` and click the
>   Install button.
>
> Terminal:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install grub2-splashimages
> ```
>
> Once installed, the images are located in the `/usr/share/images/grub`
>   folder.

In my case I was observing this picture as a splash image in grub menu, however, it does not meet all those specifications:

[image]

It could mean those specifications have been written for older grub versions.

[Reference](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Displays)