# Grub works but no display

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

My laptop: HP Probook 450 G2 (i5, 16GB, SSD). Using UEFI/GPT

I've had dual-boot on this laptop for a very long time, switching between Ubuntu, to Linux-Mint, Fedora, and now Ubuntu again.
Now, for some reason, after installing Ubuntu&grub I get a blank screen on startup.

It's important to say - **grub is working**.
If I press enter on that blank screen, Ubuntu will open. If I press down+down+enter, then Windows will open up. Just no UI appears.

What I've tried:

- update-grub & update-grub2
- Setting "GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x720" on config, following by update-grub.

I couldn't find any existing post that regards this issue.

Thanks and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Comment out your changes to GRUB_GFXMODE, and then `sudo update-grub`, then `reboot`.

Answer (score 4):

Try to open as root the file /etc/default/grub and find the following variables:

- GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT
- GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE

if GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT exists, comment it with a #

Also, set `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu` (maybe it is currently set in your machine as "hidden")

After saving the file, run `sudo upgrade-grub`

Comment: Thanks for the help. `HIDDEN` field did not exist. I did have the `STYLE` on hidden, but after changing it and `update-grub` the problem persists

Answer (score 1):

First of all try `sudo update-grub2 && reboot`.

Then you could try grub2 reinstalling:

```
sudo apt purge grub2-common grub-common grub-pc grub-gfxpayload-lists grub-pc-bin
```

chosing `Yes` to remove grub files

```
sudo apt install grub2-common grub-common grub-pc grub-gfxpayload-lists grub-pc-bin
```

chosing `/dev/sda` or whatever device with efi partition

I've tested it on virtual machine and it started after grub reinstalling. But that was a BIOS, not EFI configuration.

If something will go not as expected, you could restore it using [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/831241/925971).

Try also to [change splash image](https://askubuntu.com/a/1230000/925971) in case if your background color and text color are the same.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried following these steps. after removing and reinstalling by these exact commands, I have reached the same point as before. Blank screen of working grub

Answer (score 1):

I eventually got it working.
Steps used to get the graphics finally working:

- Reinstalling grub using [Gryu's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1235117/653505)
- Setting `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu` instead of `hidden` as in [Lorenz Keel's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1235131/653505)
- Setting `GRUB_GFXMODE` to a different resolution, found by choosing resolution on Ubuntu settings
- `grub-update`

To be honest, I'm not entirely sure the first 2 steps are necessary.
I'd recommend first checking for the correct resolution for your screen. mine was 1366X768.